# New iTunes Connect: How to resubmit after "Metadata rejected"

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted an app to to ITunes Connect and it was rejected because of incomplete metadata.
Here is what they wrote:

> If your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary.

```
To revise the metadata:

- Log in to iTunes Connect
- Click on “My Apps”
- Select your app
- Revise the desired metadata values 
- Click “Save" 
- Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review” button at the top of the App Details page
```

Great, no new binary required, so I fixed the metadata, clicked 'save' and expected to be able to resubmit for review. However, when I click the "Submit for Review", I am getting the message "You must choose a build". But in the builds section, there is no build. And, on the other hand, I can not upload a build because I don't see how I can change the app's status to "Waiting for Upload".

Please help, I am lost in the new interface of ITunes Connect... :(

Comment: You should call Apple, they are answering fast.

Comment: I found a phone for developer support, but they are only available Monday to Friday. Maybe someone else got the same problem and found a solution, I would prefer not to having to wait until Monday...

Comment: What does your app do? What did you put in the metadata that they are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Just had my app rejected today because of rating issues. Edited the rating and saved it. Then, sent a message to Apple resolution centre and after few hours the status showed Processing for App Store. I didn't submit the app for review again. It would have again taken 8 more days for review. 
Do try this before submitting the app again for review.

Comment: not click submit for reviews button if u click then queue for your apps within 5 to 8 day .

Comment: This was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here

**If your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary.**

To revise the metadata:

- Log in to iTunes Connect
- Click on “My Apps”
- Select your app
- Revise the desired metadata values
- Click “Save"
- Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review” button at the top of the App Details page

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is meant by "metadata values" ?

Comment: DO NOT Submit for Review again.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you upload a new build? I have the same problem and the Application Loader allows me to upload a new build. After you upload new build you will be able to choose the build in iTunes Connect for your app. Then you need to submit the app to review again. It looks like that "Waiting for Upload" status is retired at all.

In the same time I think that it's not acceptable to wait about a week again until Apple team makes a new decision about the app. Earlier (before new ITunes Connect redesign) they supported ability to submit only Metadata without uploading new build and new review process took no more than a couple of days for this case.
I hope Apple will fix this limitation shortly.

Note:
Maybe this answer should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation to add comments. Please excuse me.

Answer (score -3):

Follow This stpes

1) Login to itunes and Go to my apps

2) Change your binary and resubmit app

3) ready for upload process

4) Validate your app

5) Distribute your app

Comment: This does not work, because I can only upload a binary/build if the app's status is "waiting for upload". But if the app is rejected because of missing metadata, I can not switch to "waiting to upload", in line with the review's statement, that no new build is necessary, if an app is rejected because of missing metadata.

Comment: First you have cancel this rejected binary and the re-upload binary and then this option is appear.

Comment: If you resubmit a new binary after 'metadata rejected' you will have to go through another review cycle. http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/